# adt error - "... is not part of a Mac OS X Native Extensions framework"

Tags: actionscript-3, air, ane

I'm trying to package some code up as an ANE, something we've done before in house. However we're currently stuck on an ADT error which I can't seem to wrap my head around.

When running the following from a sh file, I'm getting an error.

Shell script:

```
ADT="/Applications/air/bin/adt"
NAME="VideoRoll"
AFILE="libVideoRollANE.a"


$ADT -package -target ane $NAME.ane extension.xml -swc $NAME.swc -platform iPhone-ARM -platformoptions platformoptions.xml library.swf $AFILE
```

Error:

> platformoptions.xml is not part of a Mac OS X Native Extensions
>   framework

All of the files are in the correct place and being clearly picked up by adt, as I'd assume there would be something else I'd be getting back. If you're after the source code, it's an open source library on bitbucket that I've forked and made a couple of changes to. I'm trying to compile it with Adobe AIR SDK 20 to try and fix an issue we're getting but I'm struggling to just build it from the base source right now. The source can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/lostirc/videoroll/src .

Any suggestions would be great, I'm up for trying anything now. I've modified nearly everything I can think of and tried various different orders for the command, it seems if I remove the `platformoptions` flag and value, then it gives the same error about `library.swf`, so I'm not sure it's directly related to the `platformoptions.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around the problem by running the same command on Windows. This isn't really a solution but a potential workaround for anyone having the same issue. If anyone can post a good answer then I'll accept that, but for now this is the best answer I've got.